# When a Preference is modified through the right side Toolbar Menu Form, the ToastBar message confirmation is shown to the Form beneath it

Tags: codenameone, toast

I have added the possibility to change a `Preferences` setting directly in the right side `Toolbar`. It works fine. However, the `ToastBar` confirmation messages are shown beneath the `Toolbar` `Form` rendering it effectively useless...
Is there a way to bring forth the `ToastBar` messages?

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, your question is not clear. Can you show a minimal example of code to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Thank you @FrancescoGalgani for the quick response. I managed to bypass the issue by registering a `Preferences` `addDataChangedListener` in the `init()` method. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `useFormLayeredPane(true)` when showing the toast. You can toggle this globally using:

```
ToastBar.getInstance().useFormLayeredPane(true);
```

Comment: I will check this out.